# Javascript `this` statement not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, angularjs-factory

After calling this $http request (with `server.refresh();`)

```
MinecraftServer.prototype.refresh = function(){
    return $http.get("http://mcping.net/api/" + this.ip).then(this.acceptData);
}
```

This function's `this` is the `window` object, instead of the `MinecraftServer` object:

```
MinecraftServer.prototype.acceptData = function(data){
    data = data.data

    if(data && data.online){
        this.online = data.online;
        //do more stuff       
    } else { // do more stuff }
}
```

So instead of the `MinecraftServer` object getting it's attributes updated, the `window` gets the attributes.

In case this will help, here is my abriged factory code:

```
.factory('MinecraftServer',function($http){
    function MinecraftServer(name, ip) { //does stuff }

    MinecraftServer.prototype.acceptData = function(data){
        data = data.data

        if(data && data.online){
            this.online = data.online;
            //do more stuff       
        } else { // do more stuff }
    }
    MinecraftServer.prototype.refresh = function(){return $http.get("http://mcping.net/api/" + this.ip).then(this.acceptData);}
    MinecraftServer.build = function(name, ip){return new MinecraftServer(name, ip)};
    return MinecraftServer;
})
```

Comment: You might want to read more about [how *this* works in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). It'll definitely help you get a better understanding.

Comment: @fstanis - Thanks so much! That helped me a bunch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` as a callback is using some other `this`.

Use `.bind`:

```
return $http.get("http://mcping.net/api/" + this.ip).then(this.acceptData.bind(this));
```

Comment: This seems like it works! Thanks. (I'll accept it as soon as it allows me too)

Comment: @charlietfl you have to bind to the function you want to modify `this`.